# Shapefiles tables corrupts when using in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I'm operating QGIS 2.18.0 64-bit on a 64-bit machine (Windows 10) but this issue occurred in the previous QGIS version.

When I add a shapefile that was provided to me by someone else, the attribute table is corrupted. When I save-as the shapefile as a CSV, the corruption is maintained.

When I import the shapefile into Google Earth Pro, after importing it into QGIS, the corruption is maintained.

When I add a CSV layer with multiple fields / attributes, the attribute table appears as it should. However, when I add a shapefile or even save-as a CSV to shape, the attribute table gets completely messed up. The data is corrupted because I can't even add the shapefile into Google Earth with attributes popping up as normal.
CSV looks something like this:

[image]

But when I save as a shapefile, it looks something like this:
[image]

Also, when I start up QGIS, this message pops up. 
[image]

I click 'OK' and then it starts up and I can start using it. Not sure if this message is related..

Would anyone know how to fix table corruption in QGIS?

Comment: Feels like a character encoding problem.

Comment: just a guess: try to save the csv in LibreOffice (UTF-8), Excel corrupts the csv sometime, and be sure when import the csv to set encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Only on your R6034 runtime error, it seems a [bug report #8942](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8942) is still open. If you are using QGIS 32-bit version on 64-bit Windows OS, turning to QGIS 64-bit might help.

Comment: I added info in the question. Re UTF-8 code, I will look into that and reply accordingly. Thanks for the note re the bug report. And I can confirm that I'm using QGIS 64-bit on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @user16032 it was an encoding problem. I changed to UTF-8 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments by @user30184 and user16032, it was an encoding problem. When I checked the Encoding when I save layer, add layer etc, not all were UTF-8 (maybe I changed it previously during a page scroll without knowing?). So I changed to UTF-8 and the problem went away.